# Running automatic mobile site parallel to desktop?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am buillding a website which looks great on a desktop however when i view it on a mobile it doesnt really work. I was wondering how I could set up a method/system which would automatically load the mobile site when being viewed on a device. Is there a way to do this? I have no problem with building 2 different sites but I would just like it to be automatic.

If you take a look you will see what I mean -
redchevron.co.uk

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, you shouldn't build two separate sites if you can avoid it. The general best practice is to use *responsive design* techniques to build a single site that automatically adapts its appearance and behaviour to suit different devices.

To automatically adapt the layout and styling of your site for devices, use CSS Media Queries. That's a big subject - so here's some places to start your research:

- [Beginners guide to responsive web design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design)
- [Media queries for standard devices](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)
- [Mobile first responsive design](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/)

In short - Media Queries allow browsers to use styles (and ignore others), depending on properties of the device displaying the site. For mobile, the most common technique is to set up a media query for screens smaller than *x* pixels wide, and include your mobile styles within it.

To adjust behaviour for different devices, you can use javascript to detect various attributes of the user's device (is it a touch device, for example), and adjust to suit. It's worth noting though, that your site's functionality should work without javascript - it's important to create a solid, HTML only site as the foundation for whatever other work you do.

Comment: so the concept of it is similar to an if statement? so say like - if device width is less than 480px, display X?

Comment: Exactly. How you organise your stylesheets plays a big part. I usually have a set of common styles, then a set of desktop, tablet, and phone styles, each inside a media query.